# Android Studio - не отображается кнопка Launch Standalone SDK Manager

Tags: android-studio

Добрый день. Почему-то не отображается кнопка "Launch Standalone SDK Manager". с чем это может быть связано?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Её убрали из последних версий студии. Теперь или только через студию всё делать или качать прогу для командной строки - она есть там же, где можно студию скачать.

Comment: Ясно. Спасибо большое!